# Set all button style in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I want to make my app to have several styles.

The style changes button style, textview color, and layout background color.

I have my button style in xml files.

And this is my code: style.xml (v21)

```
    <style name="ThemeIndigo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/indigo_dark</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@drawable/indigo_button</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/indigo_button</item>
</style>
```

This changes background color of all things on this layout.

How do I make my style to only change color of the buttons?

Please help. Thanks.

(Sorry for the bad english ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this style to change for just buttons in the app

```
  <style name="ThemeIndigo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
  <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
  <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: That was what I was saying! Thanks!