# How to set all button to be boarderless Android

Tags: android

so im trying to add all the buttons the next style:

```
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
```

But I dont know how to do it from the styles.xml and I dont want to add each button that style I just wanted it to be the default on that apps
I also would like to change the background color of the all the buttons

How do I do it?

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28963960/3276822
So add this 
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
to the style instead of using borderless style

Comment: I am using API15, so i cant use parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar" if i delete it and just use : 
    <style name="MyButton" >
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
    </style>
its just giving me those attribute in my buttons, but I dont want it.. I just want my button to be boardless and change his background.. I wanted to keep to default attribute and not overide them all

Comment: Your style "MyButton" will override everything if it doesn't have a parent class.
Can you look at this ? There are plenty of questions on this, perhaps if this doesn't work. I'll try on Android studio. Let me know
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom style for your button, inheriting from `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless` and then use it on a custom theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="ThemeAppCompat">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
  <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
</style>
```